# Discriminated union pattern matching by function call

Tags: f#, pattern-matching, discriminated-union

My question is inspired by this one: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21387954/pattern-matching-by-function-call)

Here is a code:

```
    type A = 
        | X of int * int
        | Y of string

    let f (A.X(a, b)) = a + b
```

It works, but with a warning: 
[image: warning]

Makes sense; I have no match for Y.

But if I add a line

```
    let f (A.Y(s)) = 10
```

Then I get an error:

[image: error]

Is there a nice way to fix it and still use pattern matching in function parameters? If not, then why did they create such strange syntax, which always leads to a warning?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to pattern match on the argument:

```
let f = function
| X(a, b) -> a + b
| Y(_) -> 10
```

When you define

```
let f (A.X(a, b)) = a + b
```

`f` has type `A -> int`, not `A.X -> int`. It is not defined for values which are instances of `A.Y`, so you get the incomplete match warning.

Your second definition of `f` also has type `A -> int` and so is a duplicate definition of the first, hence the error. If you want to write a total function over some union type you should use pattern matching with `function` or `match`.

EDIT: In response to the comment, if you have multiple arguments you want to match at the same time, you can use `match` e.g.:

```
let f a1 a2 =
    match (a1, a2) with
    | (X(a, b), X(a', b')) -> a + b
    | (X(a, b), Y(s)) -> a + 10
    | (Y(s), X(a, b)) -> 10
    | (Y(s), Y(s')) -> 20
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What you propose works fine but it seems not to solve the question in general. Suppose we had two discriminated unions  and a function with two params with pattern matching. In this case, I guess, `function` keyword wouldn't be helpful

Answer (score 4):

Some pattern matches can be complete and might be useful in function parameters, e.g. this definition of `fst` is pattern matching a tuple and is complete for all 2 tuples.

```
let fst (a,_) = a
```

Some other examples:

```
type Container = Container of string
let unwrap (Container(v)) = v

type Person = { Name:string; Age:int }
let getName {Name=name} = name
```

Comment: +1 for a very interesting example with pattern matching on records in function definition

Comment: A function definition generally takes a parenthesized pattern `(pat)`, but for a list, array or record pattern, the parens are optional.

Comment: true that, parens removed.

Answer (score 2):

As other answers say, the best way seems to be using pattern matching with `function` or `match` keywords.
However, native pattern matching of F# is pretty much powerful thing by itself. Consider the code below, **however I'm not advocating to use it in a real-world project.** I would rather use it as an exercise for better understanding of the language.

```
let f ((A.X(a, b), _ ) | (A.Y(_), (a, b))) = a + b

// usage
let x1 = f(A.X(10, 42), (100, 1)) // x1 = 52
let x2 = f(A.Y("foo"),  (100, 1)) // x2 = 101
```

What's going on here?

- The body of the function computes a sum of two values in a tuple;
- A tuple is *either* extracted from `A.X` or provided as a separate argument;
- The function takes an *extra argument* which can be considered a *fallback value*. Namely, when the first argument is `A.Y(string)`, we still need to sum *something*.
- The fallback value is ignored if the first argument has some meaning value of `A.X(int, int)`.

Yet again, don't use it blindly in real-world projects since it doesn't seem to be readable.

Further reading: [A similar approach for list processing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13998054/974789).

Comment: Wow, that's a really interesting example of pattern matching in parameters

Comment: You can use the disjunctive pattern with a constant or null-test patterns too, e.g. the null-coalescing operator `let (|?) a b = (fun (null, x | x, _) -> x) (a, b)`